# Inconsistent performance of Index

Tags: performance, postgresql-9.6, postgresql-performance

I have a table `station_logs`, when the data is small, it's really fast, but when data is large, it exponentially slow, but on some case it's faster than less rows one, I have used index, but it's doesn't really speed up:

```
                                       Table "public.station_logs"
    Column     |            Type             |                         Modifiers                         
---------------+-----------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------
 id            | integer                     | not null default nextval('station_logs_id_seq'::regclass)
 created_at    | timestamp without time zone | 
 updated_at    | timestamp without time zone | 
 deleted_at    | timestamp without time zone | 
 submitted_at  | timestamp without time zone | not null
 sequence      | integer                     | 
 level_sensor  | double precision            | 
 accel_x       | double precision            | 
 accel_y       | double precision            | 
 accel_z       | double precision            | 
 power_current | double precision            | 
 ip_address    | character varying(50)       | 
 log_type      | integer                     | 
 station_id    | integer                     | not null
 power_voltage | double precision            | 
 data          | jsonb                       | 
 is_deleted    | boolean                     | not null default false
Indexes:
    "station_logs_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "uniq_sid_sat" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (station_id, submitted_at)
    "index_station_logs_station" btree (station_id)
    "order_sid_sat" btree (station_id, submitted_at)
    "station_id__submitted_at" btree (station_id, submitted_at DESC NULLS LAST)
    "station_logs__sta_id__level_sensor__epoch" btree (station_id, level_sensor, date_part('epoch'::text, submitted_at))
    "station_logs__sta_id__submit_date" btree (station_id, date_trunc('day'::text, submitted_at))
    "submitted_at_index" btree (submitted_at)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "station_logs_station_fk" FOREIGN KEY (station_id) REFERENCES stations(id)
```

This is when the data is small:

```
 Unique  (cost=170.14..170.35 rows=41 width=20) (actual time=0.538..0.638 rows=124 loops=1)
   InitPlan 1 (returns $0)
     ->  Seq Scan on stations  (cost=0.00..3.25 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.035..0.039 rows=1 loops=1)
           Filter: (id = 319)
           Rows Removed by Filter: 99
   InitPlan 2 (returns $1)
     ->  Seq Scan on stations stations_1  (cost=0.00..3.25 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.016..0.020 rows=1 loops=1)
           Filter: (id = 319)
           Rows Removed by Filter: 99
   ->  Sort  (cost=163.64..163.74 rows=41 width=20) (actual time=0.537..0.569 rows=124 loops=1)
         Sort Key: (date_part('epoch'::text, station_logs.submitted_at))
         Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 34kB
         ->  Index Scan using station_logs__sta_id__level_sensor__epoch on station_logs  (cost=0.56..162.54 rows=41 width=20) (actual time=0.110..0.409 rows=124 loops=1)
               Index Cond: ((station_id = 319) AND (level_sensor >= COALESCE($0, '-999999'::double precision)) AND (level_sensor <= COALESCE($1, '999999'::double precision)) AND (date_part('epoch'::text, submitted_at) > '1473549517'::double precision))
 Planning time: 0.394 ms
 Execution time: 0.713 ms
```

This is when the data is medium (100k rows+)

```
 Unique  (cost=1941.10..1943.56 rows=491 width=20) (actual time=3284.501..3307.921 rows=107287 loops=1)
   InitPlan 1 (returns $0)
     ->  Seq Scan on stations  (cost=0.00..1.70 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.012..0.014 rows=1 loops=1)
           Filter: (id = 32)
           Rows Removed by Filter: 55
   InitPlan 2 (returns $1)
     ->  Seq Scan on stations stations_1  (cost=0.00..1.70 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.004..0.005 rows=1 loops=1)
           Filter: (id = 32)
           Rows Removed by Filter: 55
   ->  Sort  (cost=1937.70..1938.93 rows=491 width=20) (actual time=3284.499..3294.771 rows=107287 loops=1)
         Sort Key: (date_part('epoch'::text, station_logs.submitted_at))
         Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 3568kB
         ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on station_logs  (cost=24.09..1915.75 rows=491 width=20) (actual time=2790.056..3205.041 rows=107287 loops=1)
               Recheck Cond: ((station_id = 32) AND (level_sensor >= COALESCE($0, '-999999'::double precision)) AND (level_sensor <= COALESCE($1, '999999'::double precision)) AND (date_part('epoch'::text, submitted_at) > '1473549517'::double precision))
               Rows Removed by Index Recheck: 1139157
               Heap Blocks: exact=27733 lossy=26527
               ->  Bitmap Index Scan on station_logs__sta_id__level_sensor__epoch  (cost=0.00..23.97 rows=491 width=0) (actual time=2783.449..2783.449 rows=107287 loops=1)
                     Index Cond: ((station_id = 32) AND (level_sensor >= COALESCE($0, '-999999'::double precision)) AND (level_sensor <= COALESCE($1, '999999'::double precision)) AND (date_part('epoch'::text, submitted_at) > '1473549517'::double precision))
 Planning time: 0.252 ms
 Execution time: 3311.909 ms
```

This is when the data is large (200k rows+)

```
 Unique  (cost=5820.35..5828.00 rows=1530 width=20) (actual time=108476.667..108549.758 rows=312741 loops=1)
   InitPlan 1 (returns $0)
     ->  Seq Scan on stations  (cost=0.00..1.70 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.010..0.013 rows=1 loops=1)
           Filter: (id = 13)
           Rows Removed by Filter: 55
   InitPlan 2 (returns $1)
     ->  Seq Scan on stations stations_1  (cost=0.00..1.70 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.003..0.006 rows=1 loops=1)
           Filter: (id = 13)
           Rows Removed by Filter: 55
   ->  Sort  (cost=5816.95..5820.77 rows=1530 width=20) (actual time=108476.666..108510.791 rows=312741 loops=1)
         Sort Key: (date_part('epoch'::text, station_logs.submitted_at))
         Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 10400kB
         ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on station_logs  (cost=68.00..5736.02 rows=1530 width=20) (actual time=29821.889..108052.863 rows=312741 loops=1)
               Recheck Cond: ((station_id = 13) AND (level_sensor >= COALESCE($0, '-999999'::double precision)) AND (level_sensor <= COALESCE($1, '999999'::double precision)) AND (date_part('epoch'::text, submitted_at) > '1473549517'::double precision))
               Rows Removed by Index Recheck: 2232171
               Heap Blocks: exact=48248 lossy=53044
               ->  Bitmap Index Scan on station_logs__sta_id__level_sensor__epoch  (cost=0.00..67.61 rows=1530 width=0) (actual time=29795.634..29795.634 rows=312741 loops=1)
                     Index Cond: ((station_id = 13) AND (level_sensor >= COALESCE($0, '-999999'::double precision)) AND (level_sensor <= COALESCE($1, '999999'::double precision)) AND (date_part('epoch'::text, submitted_at) > '1473549517'::double precision))
 Planning time: 0.214 ms
 Execution time: 108561.098 ms
```

This is when the data is very large (300k rows+)

```
 Unique  (cost=7699.64..7709.91 rows=2052 width=20) (actual time=9984.816..10105.363 rows=399614 loops=1)
   InitPlan 1 (returns $0)
     ->  Seq Scan on stations  (cost=0.00..1.70 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.009..0.013 rows=1 loops=1)
           Filter: (id = 2)
           Rows Removed by Filter: 55
   InitPlan 2 (returns $1)
     ->  Seq Scan on stations stations_1  (cost=0.00..1.70 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.002..0.005 rows=1 loops=1)
           Filter: (id = 2)
           Rows Removed by Filter: 55
   ->  Sort  (cost=7696.24..7701.37 rows=2053 width=20) (actual time=9984.816..10056.801 rows=399614 loops=1)
         Sort Key: (date_part('epoch'::text, station_logs.submitted_at))
         Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 13248kB
         ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on station_logs  (cost=92.00..7583.29 rows=2053 width=20) (actual time=9574.730..9816.770 rows=399614 loops=1)
               Recheck Cond: ((station_id = 2) AND (level_sensor >= COALESCE($0, '-999999'::double precision)) AND (level_sensor <= COALESCE($1, '999999'::double precision)) AND (date_part('epoch'::text, submitted_at) > '1473549517'::double precision))
               Heap Blocks: exact=41435
               ->  Bitmap Index Scan on station_logs__sta_id__level_sensor__epoch  (cost=0.00..91.49 rows=2053 width=0) (actual time=9565.756..9565.756 rows=399614 loops=1)
                     Index Cond: ((station_id = 2) AND (level_sensor >= COALESCE($0, '-999999'::double precision)) AND (level_sensor <= COALESCE($1, '999999'::double precision)) AND (date_part('epoch'::text, submitted_at) > '1473549517'::double precision))
 Planning time: 0.219 ms
 Execution time: 10119.665 ms
```

I need to make it below 1 sec, what Index I should add?

No configuration changed on `/etc/postgresql/9.6/main/postgresql.conf` except, the RAM of my PC is 4GB, SSD disk.

```
shared_buffers = 128MB                  # min 128kB
                                        # (change requires restart)
#huge_pages = try                       # on, off, or try
                                        # (change requires restart)
#temp_buffers = 8MB                     # min 800kB
#max_prepared_transactions = 0          # zero disables the feature
                                        # (change requires restart)
# Caution: it is not advisable to set max_prepared_transactions nonzero unless
# you actively intend to use prepared transactions.
#work_mem = 4MB                         # min 64kB
#maintenance_work_mem = 64MB            # min 1MB
#replacement_sort_tuples = 150000       # limits use of replacement selection sort
#autovacuum_work_mem = -1               # min 1MB, or -1 to use maintenance_work_mem
#max_stack_depth = 2MB                  # min 100kB
dynamic_shared_memory_type = sysv       # the default is the first option
```

**EDIT 1**

added the query:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE        SELECT DISTINCT ON (2) id
                , EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM submitted_at) "submitted_at"
                , level_sensor

        FROM station_logs
        WHERE EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM submitted_at) > 1.473549517e+09
         AND station_id = '99'
                AND level_sensor >= COALESCE((SELECT min_filter FROM stations WHERE id = '99'),-999999)
                AND level_sensor <= COALESCE((SELECT max_filter FROM stations WHERE id = '99'),+999999)

        ORDER BY 2
;
```

**EDIT 2**

When executed again, it's blazing fast

```
 Unique  (cost=5820.35..5828.00 rows=1530 width=20) (actual time=1053.882..1124.823 rows=312741 loops=1)                         
   InitPlan 1 (returns $0)                                                                                                       
     ->  Seq Scan on stations  (cost=0.00..1.70 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.017..0.020 rows=1 loops=1)                        
           Filter: (id = 13)                                                                                                     
           Rows Removed by Filter: 55                                                                                            
   InitPlan 2 (returns $1)                                                                                                       
     ->  Seq Scan on stations stations_1  (cost=0.00..1.70 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.003..0.005 rows=1 loops=1)             
           Filter: (id = 13)                                                                                                     
           Rows Removed by Filter: 55                                                                                            
   ->  Sort  (cost=5816.95..5820.77 rows=1530 width=20) (actual time=1053.881..1086.823 rows=312741 loops=1)                     
         Sort Key: (date_part('epoch'::text, station_logs.submitted_at))                                                         
         Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 10400kB                                                                              
         ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on station_logs  (cost=68.00..5736.02 rows=1530 width=20) (actual time=85.960..856.237 rows=312741 loops=1)
               Recheck Cond: ((station_id = 13) AND (level_sensor >= COALESCE($0, '-999999'::double precision)) AND (level_sensor <= COALESCE($1, '999999'::double precision)) AND (date_part('epoch'::text, submitted_at) > '1473549517'::double precision))
               Rows Removed by Index Recheck: 2232171
               Heap Blocks: exact=48248 lossy=53044
               ->  Bitmap Index Scan on station_logs__sta_id__level_sensor__epoch  (cost=0.00..67.61 rows=1530 width=0) (actual time=74.643..74.643 rows=312741 loops=1)
                     Index Cond: ((station_id = 13) AND (level_sensor >= COALESCE($0, '-999999'::double precision)) AND (level_sensor <= COALESCE($1, '999999'::double precision)) AND (date_part('epoch'::text, submitted_at) > '1473549517'::double precision))
 Planning time: 0.265 ms
 Execution time: 1136.193 ms
```

**EDIT 3**

```
CREATE INDEX test_ypercube1 ON station_logs(station_id, date_part('epoch'::text, submitted_at), level_sensor, id);
```

After adding index:

```
 Unique  (cost=5922.45..5930.25 rows=1559 width=20) (actual time=1134.800..1207.952 rows=312741 loops=1)
   InitPlan 1 (returns $0)
     ->  Seq Scan on stations  (cost=0.00..1.70 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.016..0.018 rows=1 loops=1)
           Filter: (id = 13)
           Rows Removed by Filter: 55
   InitPlan 2 (returns $1)
     ->  Seq Scan on stations stations_1  (cost=0.00..1.70 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.003..0.005 rows=1 loops=1)
           Filter: (id = 13)
           Rows Removed by Filter: 55
   ->  Sort  (cost=5919.05..5922.95 rows=1559 width=20) (actual time=1134.798..1168.616 rows=312741 loops=1)
         Sort Key: (date_part('epoch'::text, station_logs.submitted_at))
         Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 10400kB
         ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on station_logs  (cost=68.44..5836.38 rows=1559 width=20) (actual time=158.752..935.266 rows=312741 loops=1)
               Recheck Cond: ((station_id = 13) AND (level_sensor >= COALESCE($0, '-999999'::double precision)) AND (level_sensor <= COALESCE($1, '999999'::double precision)) AND (date_part('epoch'::text, submitted_at) > '1473549517'::double precision))
               Rows Removed by Index Recheck: 2232171
               Heap Blocks: exact=48248 lossy=53044
               ->  Bitmap Index Scan on station_logs__sta_id__level_sensor__epoch  (cost=0.00..68.05 rows=1559 width=0) (actual time=149.239..149.239 rows=312741 loops=1)
                     Index Cond: ((station_id = 13) AND (level_sensor >= COALESCE($0, '-999999'::double precision)) AND (level_sensor <= COALESCE($1, '999999'::double precision)) AND (date_part('epoch'::text, submitted_at) > '1473549517'::double precision))
 Planning time: 0.481 ms
 Execution time: 1218.998 ms
```

Comment: Will you show us the query that is slow?

Comment: hi, sorry, i forgot to add, it's the exact same query for each one, just with different station_id

Comment: the 100k rows took 3s, 200k rows took 200s, the 300k rows took 10s '__') that's the weird part.

Comment: Can you try adding an index on `(station_id, date_part('epoch'::text, submitted_at), level_sensor, id)` ?

Comment: I haven't added the index, but when I execute again the exact same query for the 200k rows+, it's done in 1 sec.

Comment: i have add the index (on `EDIT 3`), but it was not used on the query..

Comment: Hm, the other index is still used. Can you tell us how many rows would be returned if you removed the `DISTINCT ON` from the query?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66498/discussion-between-kokizzu-and-ypercube).